# Why is my trackBy function auto refreshing in the console in a loop?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase

I'm trying to use trackBy in *ngFor but it's auto refreshinging in an infinite loop and I'm not sure why.

```js
  trackByTopics(index: number, topic: any): string {
    console.log('trackby', topic, index);
    return topic.id;
  }
```

```html
<mat-list *ngFor="let topic of groupTopics; trackBy:trackByTopics">
```

GroupTopics is coming from a firebase snapshot observable:

```js
  getGroupTopics(groupId: string) {
    this.groupTopics = [];
    const chatQuery = this.groupSvc.getGroupChats(groupId)
      .orderBy('updated', 'desc');

    chatQuery.onSnapshot((snapShot) => {
      snapShot.forEach(async (data) => {
        this.groupTopics.push({
          id: data.id,
          userId: data.data().userId,
          displayName: data.data().displayName,
          title: data.data().title,
          description: data.data().description,
          profilePic: await this.getUserPhoto(data.data().userId),
          days: moment().diff(data.data().createdAt, 'days')
        });
      });
      console.log('this.groupTopics', this.groupTopics);
    });
  }
```

And this is what I'm seeing in the console:
[image]

Comment: Possibly a sign that something is periodically causing your view to be re-rendered, thus triggering your custom `trackBy` function repeatedly. Also check if `groupTopics` is a stable reference?

Comment: @miqh could this be because groupTopics is getting data from a firebase .snapshot observable?